# In CSS Grid using auto-fit how to make one cell occupy 2 columns?

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

You can check code over [here](http://jsbin.com/sirudiqupa/edit?html,css,output). I want the first cell to occupy 2 columns and the rest of the cells to occupy 1 column . Is there a way to do that while using auto-fit for columns in CSS grid?

```
<h2>Auto-fit</h2>
<div class="wrapper fit">
    <div class="col-2">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
    <div class="">5</div>
    <div class="">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
}

.fit {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay made it work.

For the cell you want to increase the column count you have to specify the `grid-column` for it.

So in the above example for the first cell specify

```
.col-2 {
  grid-column: 1  /3;
}
```

To make the grid wrap to only 1 column per row add a media query.

```
.col-2{
    grid-column: 1/3;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 33em) {
        grid-column: 1/2;
   }
}
```

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sirudiqupa/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
}
.fit div{border:1px solid black;}

.fit {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.col-2{
grid-column:1/3;
}
```

```html
<h2>Auto-fit</h2>
<div class="wrapper fit">
    <div class="col-2">1</div>
    <div class="">2</div>
    <div class="">3</div>
    <div class="">4</div>
    <div class="">5</div>
    <div class="">6</div>
</div>
```